# How to calculate inputs for performace and load testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

How to calculate inputs (virtual users, ram up period) for performance and load testing using Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing [Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) - you are supposed to be checking your system behaviour against the **anticipated load**, it means that you should know the expected number of users from [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)

If you don't have any requirements - go for the [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), i.e. start with 1 user and [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) until response time starts increasing or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first)

With regards to the ramp-up period duration - there are no strict requirements, as per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.**

so if you don't have any better ideas - just go for the above recommendation.